# Updating null geometries from attribute using ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, field-calculator, python-parser, null-geometry

I have a large point feature class and have realised that there are several hundred features with null geometry. Fortunately the coordinates are stored as an attribute. What I need to do is update the geometry of the points with the x and y stores in the attribute table.

After a little search I found an Esri Support Services Blog post on [How to Update the Location of a Point Feature and Its XY Fields](https://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2011/12/06/how-to-update-the-location-of-a-point-feature-and-its-xy-fields/) which includes a python function that will do this for me in the field calculator.

However, it seems that this will only work on features with a geometry. When I run it on the null geometry features it returns a syntax error. presumably this is because there is no shape or there is no shape.getpart(0).

Is there something I could add to this script to allow it to update null geometries, or does anyone have another method?

Comment: In field calculator, Python select shape field and type arcpy.Point(!x!,!y!). Set environment Extent to something very big

Comment: Duh, so simple! I cant believe I spent so much time messing about. That's worked - if you write is as an answer I'll accept. Thanks

Comment: Nyet, no answer. It's most likely a duplicate. Glad it works

Comment: The duplicate is not identical but uses the same concept for its solution which is that the Shape field can be updated by field calculating its X and Y values.